# ng-show and ng-change unwanted delay

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I'm new with angularjs and firebase. I'm trying to make a form where the user insert the username. Everytime that the `<input>` changes I check if the username is already taken or is free. If the username is already taken I want to show a `<p>` that says "The username is already taken".

**The problem is this**: if I insert a username already taken (for example "*Damiano*") the console says "the username is not ok" but the `<p>` paragraph with ng-show doesn't appear. But if I add a single letter to the username (for example "*Damianox*") the console says "the username is ok" and the `<p>` paragraph appears! But it musn't appear because the username "Damianox" is free!

It seems that there's a delay of a letter!

This is the code and sorry for the bad english!

This is fistime.html

```
<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="txtTitle">Username</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" id="txtUsername" ng-model="user.username" ng-change="verifyuser();"  placeholder="Be imaginative" class="form-control input-md">
    <p ng-show="invalidUsername"> The username is already taken</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is firstime.js

```
.controller('FirstimeCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebase','$location', 'CommonProp', function($scope, $firebase, $location ,CommonProp) {

    $scope.verifyuser = function(){

                //var invalidName = $scope.invalidUsername;
                var newUsername = $scope.user.username;
                var msg = $scope.invalidMsg;

                var ref = new Firebase("https://instafame.firebaseio.com");
                var q = ref.child("users").orderByChild("username").equalTo(newUsername);     

                    q.once("value", function(snapshot){
                        if (snapshot.val() === null){
                            $scope.invalidUsername = false;
                            console.log("the username is ok")
                        }else{
                            $scope.invalidUsername = true;
                            console.log("the username is not ok")

                        }

                    })}
```

Thanks in advance <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is a that the change of `invalidUsername` doesn't trigger a new digest circle in your case.

You could workaround this problem by using a `$timeout`. 
After you injected `$timeout` you can change your code (i simplified your if/else case here):

```
q.once("value", function(snapshot){
     $timeout(function(){
          $scope.invalidUsername = snapshot.val() === null;
     });
})}
```

Comment: I think that `$scope.$evalAsync` would be a better option here. `$evalAsync` is more likely to execute in the same digest, rather than being forced to the next one with `$timeout`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!

Comment: It runs! It runs! Perfectly! Yeah! Thank you so much @lexit! Greeeeeeaaaaat!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `ng-change` on your input. If memory serves, the change from `ng-model` to your model happens at a different digest cycle than the `ng-change` handler.

Instead of using `ng-change`, use `$watch` on your model. Add this to your controller, and remove the `ng-change` attrbute:

```
$scope.$watch('user', $scope.verifyUser, true);
```

The `true` is there to do a "deep watch", so it will trigger when any property or sub-property of `user` changes. The handler function will also receive both new and old values as parameters.

Read more about `$watch` here:
[scope.$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

Comment: While my answer may be not best practice, your solution should be avoided because manually adding watchers will eventually make a huge performance impact especially deep watchers.

Comment: He's adding a single watcher. It's worth noting that watchers can impact performance and should be used judiciously, but advocating never using them isn't valid IMO.

Comment: @Artless Sorry, can you be more specific in the code? Where do I have to add the $scope.$watch('user', $scope.verifyuser, true); ? Randomly in the controller?

Comment: @RadamesFabioSoulmathe Yes, just place it anywhere.